Cannot start service php: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task
I want to dockerize my laravel application but I am getting this error
ERROR: for backend_php_1  Cannot start service php: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "entrypoint.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
Dockerfile
FROM php:8.2 as php

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y unzip libpq-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql bcmath

#RUN pecl install -o -f redis \
#    && rm -rf /tmp/pear \
#    && docker-php-ext-enable redis

WORKDIR /var/www
COPY . .

COPY --from=composer:2.7.4 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

ENV PORT=8000
ENTRYPOINT [ "entrypoint.sh" ]

docker-compose
version: "3.8"
services:

    # PHP Service
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            target: php
            args:
                - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
        environment:
            - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
            - CONTAINER_ROLE=app
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        depends_on:
            - database

volumes:
    db-data: ~

entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f "vendor/autoload.php" ]; then
    composer install --no-progress --no-interaction
fi

if [ ! -f ".env" ]; then
    echo "Creating env file for env $APP_ENV"
    cp .env.example .env
else
    echo "env file exists."
fi

role=${CONTAINER_ROLE:-app}
echo role
if [ "$role" = "app" ]; then
    php artisan migrate
    php artisan key:generate
    php artisan cache:clear
    php artisan config:clear
    php artisan route:clear
    php artisan serve --port=$PORT --host=0.0.0.0 --env=.env
    exec docker-php-entrypoint "$@"
fi


Is the entrypoint.sh anywhere in the standard search $PATH, or does it need to be ./entrypoint.sh?  The volumes: overwrite everything in the image with content from the host, including this entrypoint script, and there are also potential lurking problems around for example DOS line endings on Windows systems.

@DavidMaze entrypoint.sh is on the root folder and Dockerfile should be a ble to locate it. everything is copied from the current location to www

It looks like there might be a couple of things wrong.
Path
Update your ENTRYPOINT as follows:
ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]

This (the ./ before the filename) is to cater for the fact that the /var/www is not on your execution path.
This should resolve the executable file not found in $PATH error.
Permissions
You should also ensure that the entrypoint.sh is executable (on the host!).
chmod u+x entrypoint.sh

On the host you'd then have something like this (The x on the line for entrypoint.sh is important.):
-rw-rw-r-- 1 423 Apr 25 06:09 docker-compose.yml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 289 Apr 25 06:10 Dockerfile
-rwxrw-r-- 1 615 Apr 25 06:04 entrypoint.sh

You need this because your docker-compose.yml is mounting the current directory onto the image at /var/www. So when the container runs the entrypoint.sh it's actually running the one from the volume mount rather than the one copied onto the image.
This should resolve the permission denied error.
